Any solution for this issue that SignalR is not working in .NET 8?
When I am using SignalR with ASP.NET Core 8, the messages are not sent and received using Postman. I have added breakpoints even though the code is not hitting on breakpoints.
Any idea to solve this issue?
ChatHub.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ChatService.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserConnected", Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnected", Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using ChatService.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseWebSockets();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");

await app.RunAsync();


Can you remove this line: app.UseWebsockets(), you don't need it

Do you have any logging within your application? Is there anything captured there?
